# I am unable to deactivate the active App Bundle. I need it to be able to update app that doesn't comply Google Play Policies

Tags: android, google-play-console, policy, android-app-bundle

I have an app that includes a version of the SDK that doesn't comply with Google Play policies.
When trying to upload the new version, it does not let it go to production, it says this:
MANDATORY ACTION: Upload a new compliant version AND deactivate the non-compliant version.

I've uploaded a new version but it won't let me send it to production until I deactivate the old one, but I can't find a way to deactivate it.

I have looked through the Google Play Console for hours and there is no way to disable the App Bundle that is active. There is no option to disable it.